# Reading json file with multiple objects python

Tags: python, json

Hey I am newbie working with JSON files 
 I have a sample `JSON` file like this (twitter data scrape)
here each`[]` contains multiple JSON objects, I want to extract the text from these objects, the problem is `json.load` is not working on multiple JSON array structure `([][][])`
    in the sample example below first `[]` contains three JSON objects and second one has 2 JSON objects

```
[{
            "created_at": "2014-12-07 02:17:18", 
            "favorite_count": 5, 
            "id_str": "541416129567019008", 
            "in_reply_to_screen_name": "panellington", 
            "retweet_count": 15, 
            "retweeted": false, 
            "text": "minutes ago. #berkeley #BlackLivesMatter #EricGarner #LAPD"
        },
        {
            "created_at": "2014-12-04 19:21:13", 
            "favorite_count": 13, 
            "id_str": "540586640595369984", 
            "in_reply_to_screen_name": null, 
            "retweet_count": 38, 
            "retweeted": false, 
            "text": "#BlackLivesMatter"
        },
        {
            "created_at": "2014-12-13 00:50:27", 
            "favorite_count": 1, 
            "id_str": "543568596299808768", 
            "in_reply_to_screen_name": null, 
            "retweet_count": 0, 
            "retweeted": false, 
            "text": "MLK Riot is language of unheard #Ferguson #ICantBreathe #BlackLivesMatter"
        }]

[{
            "created_at": "2015-04-28 13:21:35", 
            "favorite_count": 0, 
            "id_str": "593042377658519552", 
            "in_reply_to_screen_name": null, 
            "retweet_count": 5, 
            "retweeted": false, 
            "text": "RT @fsmith827: A lot of folks speaking against civil unrest have been willfully blind, willfully silent @ #BlackLivesMatter &amp; #PoliceBrutal\u2026", 
        },
        {
            "created_at": "2014-12-07 03:17:27", 
            "favorite_count": 0, 
            "id_str": "541431264897937408", 
            "in_reply_to_screen_name": null, 
            "retweet_count": 456, 
            "retweeted": false, 
            "text": "RT @thecrisismag: #ICantBreathe  Protesters in Paris march in solidarity with #EricGarner and #MikeBrown  #BlackLivesMatter #GrandJury" 

}]
```

I want to read it as JSON object and want to work on this (ex: `data[0]['text']`)

Problem is my file contains multiple JSON array objects [some random number of JSON objects],[some random number of JSON objects] and so on..

```
    with open('tweets.json') as json_data:
        d = json.load(json_data)
```

> json.load is not working because of this `[][][]`... structure

```
    ## error raised 
    Error: 
        raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)

    JSONDecodeError: Extra data
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm not clear what you're trying to do here. But it looks like you simply want to iterate over your list of json strings. Something like this:

```
In [1]: import json

In [2]: json_data = ['{ "created_at": "2014-12-07 02:17:18", "favorite_count": 5, "id_str": "541416129567019008", "in_reply_to_screen_name": "panellington", "retweet
   ...: _count": 15, "retweeted": false, "text": "minutes ago. #berkeley #BlackLivesMatter #EricGarner #LAPD" }', '{ "created_at": "2014-12-04 19:21:13", "favorite_c
   ...: ount": 13, "id_str": "540586640595369984", "in_reply_to_screen_name": null, "retweet_count": 38, "retweeted": false, "text": "#BlackLivesMatter" }', '{ "crea
   ...: ted_at": "2014-12-13 00:50:27", "favorite_count": 1, "id_str": "543568596299808768", "in_reply_to_screen_name": null, "retweet_count": 0, "retweeted": false,
   ...:  "text": "MLK Riot is language of unheard #Ferguson #ICantBreathe #BlackLivesMatter" }']

In [3]: for tweet in json_data:
   ...:     print(json.loads(tweet))
   ...:
{'created_at': '2014-12-07 02:17:18', 'favorite_count': 5, 'id_str': '541416129567019008', 'in_reply_to_screen_name': 'panellington', 'retweet_count': 15, 'retweeted': False, 'text': 'minutes ago. #berkeley #BlackLivesMatter #EricGarner #LAPD'}
{'created_at': '2014-12-04 19:21:13', 'favorite_count': 13, 'id_str': '540586640595369984', 'in_reply_to_screen_name': None, 'retweet_count': 38, 'retweeted': False, 'text': '#BlackLivesMatter'}
{'created_at': '2014-12-13 00:50:27', 'favorite_count': 1, 'id_str': '543568596299808768', 'in_reply_to_screen_name': None, 'retweet_count': 0, 'retweeted': False, 'text': 'MLK Riot is language of unheard #Ferguson #ICantBreathe #BlackLivesMatter'}
```

Comment: if it would have been single array then that is possible but my file has multiple arrays like that 

[{ },{ }] [{ }] i.e, list of list of json strings

Comment: Just iterate over the lists and then iterate over the tweets, then,

```for tweet_list in json_data:
    for tweet in tweet_list:
        print(json.loads(tweet))```

Comment: with open('tweets_1.json') as json_data:
    for tweet_list in json_data:
        for line in tweet_list:
            print(line)

something like this ??
but it's reading in string format

Comment: What is in string format? I only see strings in a few places in the code you posted. For example "created at": "2014-12-07 02:17:18"